# How to configure uWSGI to use ssl-socket instead of socket

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi, wsgi, uwsgi

I have an Apache reverse proxy server with a config:

```
ProxyPass /hub06/ uwsgi://myotherserver:8006/
ProxyPassReverse /hub06/ uwsgi://myotherserver:8006/
```

Then I have a second server running a Django app with uwsgi setup like this:

```
ssl-socket=0.0.0.0:8006,/home/user1/server.crt,/home/user1/server.key,HIGH
```

I am getting internal server error. When I use a plain socket without a certificate:

```
socket=0.0.0.0:8006
```

It works perfectly well.

Any ideas how to make ssl-socket work please?

Answer (score 0):

mod_proxy_uwsgi does not currently support uwsgi over ssl (albeit it should be an easy addition). If you need ssl for backends, you may want to use https-socket (instead of ssl-socket) and mod_proxy_http